# 2.8 Shortcut to turn on/off "Emulate 3 Button Mouse"..?

Tags: customization

Could use some insight please, I am not sure how to properly formulate this question (brand new to 3D and Blender 2.8). After reading up on various forums there maybe a way to reprogram a keymap shortcut for the ALT key?

I prefer having the "**emulate 3 Button Mouse**" checked for general tumbling/navigation so I don't have to use the MMB when zooming or nudging viewport but when  "emulate 3 Button Mouse" is checked it nukes the ability to employ the ALT key for selecting edge loops/rings.

I found that Left Double Click works although selection is limited and does not do half of what is available as far as selecting/deselecting goes... Hmmm?

Sorry for long scenario here, not sure if there is a workaround. It's be nice though.

Thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: I wanted this as I find using the MMB to be a bit of a strain compared to the other buttons, I agree it is easier to use the ALT key for rotating the camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender's keymap requires an operator to execute when the shortcut is pressed. Currently there is no operator to toggle the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* option from the preferences, but this can be solved by writing a little add-on.

The following add-on creates an operator that allows to toggle the preference option and can therefore be added as a shortcut into your keymap. Copy & paste the script into a file and save it with the `.py` file extension.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Toggle 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse'",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "Edit > Operator Search",
    "description": "Operator for toggeling the 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse' option.",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Preferences"}

import bpy


class PREFERENCES_OT_toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "preferences.toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse"
    bl_label = "Toggle 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse'"

    def execute(self, context):
        context.preferences.inputs.use_mouse_emulate_3_button = not context.preferences.inputs.use_mouse_emulate_3_button
        return {"FINISHED"}


classes = (PREFERENCES_OT_toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse,)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

You can install the add-on in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*.

[image: Install add-on]

Once it's installed you will have to enable it. You can find it in the *Preferences* category.

[image: Activate add-on]

Then switch to the *Keymap* in the preferences and add a shortcut referencing the operator from the add-on. You'll have to decide what key binding you'd like to use.

[image: Keymap entry]

Comment: wow thank you, this is way above my level of expertise but I will try my best. I am only guessing but do I save the script as a .py or is there a file extension blender prefers ?

Comment: Yes, you need to copy & paste the code into a file and save it with `.py` extension, for example `toggle_emulate_3_mouse_button.py`. In the preferences in the *Add-ons* section there is an *Install* button at the top. Click it and select the file.

Comment: It should show up in the list of add-ons afterwards. You need to enable it by clicking on the checkbox next to it.

Comment: I did it..! You Sir are a genius! Thank you so much. It took a bunch of attempts but made it work.

Comment: @halipino You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: 10 stars **********

Answer (score 2):

Building on Robert Gützkow's excellent answer and script, I've updated the script to perform a similar task for Emulate Numpad, and which also applies the hotkeys for your particular concern (Toggling Emulate Middle Mouse Button) that involved an extra manual step in Robert's Answer:

> `"` for *Toggle Emulate Middle Mouse Button*

> `;` for *Toggle Emulate Numpad*

You may change these hotkeys in the Preferences.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Toggle 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse' & 'Emulate Numpad'",
    "author": "brybalicious courtesy Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 1),
    "location": "Edit > Operator Search",
    "description": "Operator for toggling the 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse' & 'Emulate Numpad' options",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "https://github.com/brybalicious/toggle_mmb_numpad/wiki",
    "category": "Preferences"}

import bpy
import rna_keymap_ui
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

# Surfacing the Operators
# They can now be looked up via their bl_label attribute with the search function on default hotkey F3

class PREFERENCES_OT_toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "preferences.toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse"
    bl_label = "Toggle 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse'"

    def execute(self, context):
        context.preferences.inputs.use_mouse_emulate_3_button = not context.preferences.inputs.use_mouse_emulate_3_button
        return {"FINISHED"}

class PREFERENCES_OT_toggle_emulate_numpad(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "preferences.toggle_numpad"
    bl_label = "Toggle 'Emulate Numpad'"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.preferences.inputs.use_emulate_numpad = not bpy.context.preferences.inputs.use_emulate_numpad
        return {"FINISHED"}


# Keymap Code

# First, set up a dictionary of key mappings.

# "TEMPLATE": [{"label": "Human readable name of keymap in Blender Keymap UI",
#               "region_type": "WINDOW", //Default is WINDOW (optional)
#               "space_type", "EMPTY", //Default is EMPTY
#               "map_type": "KEYBOARD", //Device to be used (optional)
#               "keymap": "Window", //Name to be chosen from declared list of keymap names
#               "idname": ..., //Specific reference to operator from blender API
#               "type": "", //Key type identifier - choose a specific keyboard button or mouse button, etc...
#               "ctrl": False, //Combination keys for compound hotkeys (optional)
#               ...
#               "value": "PRESS"}, //Whether key will be held, pressed, etc...
#              {...}]

keys = {"MENU": [{"label": "Toggle Emulate 3 Button Mouse",
                  "region_type": "WINDOW",
                  "space_type": "EMPTY",
                  "map_type": "KEYBOARD",
                  "keymap": "Window",
                  "idname": "preferences.toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse",
                  "type": "QUOTE",
                  "ctrl": False,
                  "alt": False,
                  "shift": False,
                  "oskey": False,
                  "value": "PRESS"
                  },
                {"label": "Toggle Emulate Numpad",
                  "region_type": "WINDOW",
                  "space_type": "EMPTY",
                  "map_type": "KEYBOARD",
                  "keymap": "Window",
                  "idname": "preferences.toggle_numpad",
                  "type": "SEMI_COLON",
                  "ctrl": False,
                  "alt": False,
                  "shift": False,
                  "oskey": False,
                  "value": "PRESS"
                  }]}

# Define a function to get a list of key mappings, 'keylists'
def get_keys():
    keylists = []
    keylists.append(keys["MENU"])
    return keylists

# Define a function to register the key mappings templated in the dict as keymaps, using the constructor kc.keymaps.new()        
def register_keymaps(keylists):
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon

    keymaps = []

    for keylist in keylists:
        for item in keylist:
            keymap = item.get("keymap")
            space_type = item.get("space_type", "EMPTY")
            region_type = item.get("region_type", "WINDOW")

            if keymap:
                km = kc.keymaps.new(name=keymap, space_type=space_type, region_type=region_type)
                # km = kc.keymaps.new(name=keymap, space_type=space_type)

                if km:
                    idname = item.get("idname")
                    type = item.get("type")
                    value = item.get("value")

                    shift = item.get("shift", False)
                    ctrl = item.get("ctrl", False)
                    alt = item.get("alt", False)
                    oskey = item.get("oskey", False)

                    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(idname, type, value, shift=shift, ctrl=ctrl, alt=alt, oskey=oskey)

                    if kmi:
                        properties = item.get("properties")

                        if properties:
                            for name, value in properties:
                                setattr(kmi.properties, name, value)

                        keymaps.append((km, kmi))
    return keymaps

# Define a function to unregister the keymaps
def unregister_keymaps(keymaps):
    for km, kmi in keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)


classes = (PREFERENCES_OT_toggle_emulate_3_button_mouse, PREFERENCES_OT_toggle_emulate_numpad)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    global keymaps
    keys = get_keys()
    keymaps = register_keymaps(keys)



def unregister():
    global keymaps
    for km, kmi in keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)

    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)


# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     register()
```

To install, please download or clone the repository from https://github.com/brybalicious/toggle_mmb_numpad.git and follow the same instructions for installing the addon as an archive with `.zip` extension, as per Robert's answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ineresting, but please prefer past the code here instead of refering an external link. Thanks you.

Comment: sure thing @lemon I updated with the code inline. If the answer is satisfactory now, please rate it :)

Comment: I like this automates adding the keymap, I did find that using the double quote didn't work right.  It seems you cannot use any key in preferences > Keymap that requires you to hold down the shift key first for a symbol, it only picks up left shift or right shift.  It works to set in code but I could not reliably get the shortcut key to work.

Comment: It's a few more keys but I used Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Q.  Blender does have quite a few functions, single letter shortcut keys are probably all used already :).